# How to protect an API service with bearer tokens if I don't control the auth service

Tags: security, azure, authentication, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

I need to make a mobile app which will have a login screen, the login screen will use an authentication service provided by our client, which with username and password will return some basic profile info and something they call a token. I don't think it's a Bearer token, the service they developed checks against LDAP.

Then I have to develop services that will take data from some database, however our services won't be installed on the customer's datacenter, it will probably be a service fabric cluster in Azure.

How do I protect those services, so that they can only be called by the authenticated users?

I found this article:
https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core

But I guess that it's not the same thing because authentication is in one domain. My services will be in another datacenter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question, your use case is:

- Mobile service sends a login request to the authentication service and gets back some token. (As far as you're concerned this is opaque and you don't have any influence over how it works.)
- The mobile app needs to use that token to make authenticated requests to another service, which does not live on the same network or infrastructure as the authentication service.

The problem is that you need some way for your other services to verify the authenticity of the token, without having access to the service that handles authentication and issues tokens. (If I've misunderstood the problem, please clarify.)

There are two solutions that come to mind:

- If your new services can call back to the authentication service to verify a token, then the solution is easy. Just have your services talk to the authentication service over HTTPS and make sure the token is valid.
- If the token is signed in a way that you can verify independently (for example, a JWT signed with an asymmetric key, or a known symmetric key), then your new services might be able to verify it without talking to the authorization service. In this case, your new services would need to ensure the token hasn't expired and the signature checks out.